# how to tap android view or textview page up or page down

Tags: android, textview

How can I have a full screen textview page up and page down by tapping the top of the view or the bottom of the view?

I have tried using page up and page down buttons at the top and bottom of the textview, but it is wasted space.

if the textview is read only, tapping the top or bottom of the view should allow me to page up or page down through the content.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions
Dean-O

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to the view.Then you'll get to coordinates of where the view was tapped in the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) that gets passes in the on touch method. You can figure out if it was a tap by calling a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat.html) in the on touch method. Knowing the coordinates and the gesture, you can make the view scroll appropriately.

You can use the [GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) as your GestureListener in the constructor and just override the onSingleTapConfirmed method and do the scrolling as you want it.

Make sure to return true if you consume the gesture. Also make sure to pass on the result of the GestureDetector.

EDIT:
If you want something simpler, you can just make two invisible views float on top of your view and make their clicks do the scrolling.

EDIT 2: To implement the page up and page down you need to put the TextView inside a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) and scroll the view by the length of the page. In case you want to disable the regular scroll by swipe or fling you can make a custom view that extends scroll view and override its [onInterceptTouchevent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) method

EDIT 3: looking at your code in the comments I see you're using a MovementMethod for scrolling. If you wish to do that you will have to create a custom [BaseMovementMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/MovementMethod.html). Its this method that causes the scrolling. You can override its ontouchevent to implement your page up and page down. You don't need the invisible views. I was not aware of this class before and now see that that might be the best possible way of doing it. Just create a class like this:

```
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.method.BaseMovementMethod;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class PagingMovementMethod extends BaseMovementMethod{
    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }
    });
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable text, MotionEvent event) {

        boolean singleTap= gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        if(singleTap){
            if(event.getX()<widget.getHeight()/2){
                pageUp(widget,text);
            }else {
                pageDown(widget,text);
            }
        }
        return singleTap;
    }
}
```

If you assign this to your TextView it should work without any other views.

Comment: I have added the two invisible buttons, but tapping on them is not scrolling the textview.
      void Page_Up() {
  mBodyText.setMovementMethod(new 
                ScrollingMovementMethod());
 }

 void Page_Down() {
  mBodyText.setMovementMethod(new 
                  ScrollingMovementMethod());

 }

I do not see how to make them page up or page down

Comment: did you set the visiblity to invisible... because that renders them unclickable...what i meant by invisible is views with `android:background = "#0000"`

Comment: no I set them as transparent   would that also make them unclickable?   I dont see where I have programmed it to go page down or page up.  There is it just android magic?

Comment: I just understood the method you're using...making another edit that will help...wait for EDIT3

Comment: Thanks, how to I assign this class to my textview?

Comment: mBodyText.setMovementMethod(new PagingMovementMethod());

Answer (score 0):

Just create 2 `Buttons` with transparent background and place them at top and bottom. This is the easiest solution.

Comment: I did that and have set them to call my page up or page down methods which contain the mBodyText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());  but how do I program it to scroll a page down or a page up?